# Identical statement condition

Tags: php, if-statement, isset

Correct me if I'm wrong. I saw many people write condition header as this format.

```
if(isset($var) && $var!=""){}
```

Basically it just checking if $var isn't null value right? In my understanding this would be enough.

```
if($var){}
```

Am I missing something? Did my method unreliable? My colleague already pointed out that I should use the first one. Sometime I just lazy to write so I just want to make it simple.

Answer (score 3):

They are not the same thing.

`if (expr)` is evaluated with these rules -> http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php#types.comparisons

```
<?php

$var = "0";

if (isset($var) && $var != "") {
    echo "first block\n";
}

if ($var) {
    echo "second block\n";
}
```

[Example](https://eval.in/private/f652c6dec5da38)

Suppose $var is "0", then it is definitely isset, and not equal to an empty string, but fails the `if ($var)` test.

Answer (score 1):

`php
if($var){}`

will check if `$var` is true. In this scenario, if `$var` is used for first time in condition, notice will be generated that you are trying to use undefined variable.

Answer (score 1):

1. The **isset ()** function is used to check whether a variable is set or not. If variable is not set, possibly it will enter to the **else** condition.

In your case if $var is not available, Possibly you will hit by this error  **Undefined variable: var**. So checking isset is always good for your code.

**Case 1:**

```
if($var){
    echo 'pass';
}else{
    echo 'fail';
}
```

**Output:Notice: Undefined variable: var in E:\siva\htdocs\test.php on line 48
fail**

**Case 2:**

```
if(isset($var)){
    echo 'pass';
}else{
    echo 'fail';
}
```

**Output : fail**

**Case 3:**

```
$var = '';
if($var){
    echo 'pass';
}else{
    echo 'fail';
}
```

**Output :Fail**

In this case 3 is more interesting, If you failed to use isset, Defined the variable as null, So you will not get the error